# C# object does not contain a definition for method

Tags: c#

I apologize for the stupid question but I'm new to C# and have not been able to find help from the other questions related to this error.

I've created a class called "Sender" but I can't access my method when I instantiate an object.  When I try and call my method I get the error: "object does not contain a definition for sendMessage."  I don't know where I am going wrong.  Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your help!

This is my Sender class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace CS5200_HW1_GUI
{
    public class Sender
    {
        private UdpClient myUdpClient;
        private IPEndPoint localEP;
        string ipAddress = "129.123.41.1";
        string _port = "12001";

        public void sendMessage()
        {

        }
       // byte[] sendBuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(command);
       // int result = myUdpClient.Send(sendBuffer, sendBuffer.Length, localEP);

     }
 }
```

This is where I'm trying to call the method:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

    namespace CS5200_HW1_GUI
    {
         public partial class Form1 : Form
         {
              //private UdpClient myUdpClient;
              IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
              string command = string.Empty;
              string newWord = String.Empty;
              string guess = String.Empty;
              string dashes = String.Empty;
              string newAddress = string.Empty;
              string newPort = string.Empty;
              int score = 0;
              int length = 0;
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              Random random = new Random();

              Sender sender = new Sender();

              private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {
                   command = "NewGame";
                   sender.sendMessage(command);             //I get the error here
                   newWord = receiver.receiveMessage();
                   length = newWord.Length;
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: sendMessage method doesnt take an argument  should be sendMessage() not sendMessage(command)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because sender is both an Sender  object and also one of the arguments of the click handler.

Pay attention to the method signature:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

You are referring to the closest sender, which is of type `object`. To solve this you have to rename either or call it with `this`.

Example:

```
this.sender.sendMessage()
```

Comment: I totally missed the scope - good catch @Areks! He's also got a problem with the parameter passing.

Comment: Thank you!  As soon as I am allowed to do so, I will accept your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. But pay attention to Bradley's answer. He's also correct about they way you are calling the method. You are passing an argument to a method which can not accept any (because you declared it that way).

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `sender.sendMessage` with a argument (`command`)

The only function called `sendMessage` on the `Sender` object does not take any parameters, so a matching method is not found.

You also are using the `sender` variable, which is a variable within the `Click` method (due to the signature). You should use a different name.

Comment: then the error will be like `there is no overloaded method`

Comment: @Shaharyar I noticed the other error too late :( It will still be a problem after he fixes the other error though.

Comment: Yes you are right. There are two errors, but `method not found` error comes before the `overloaded method` error. +1 for catching another error.